# Numba "Operator Overload in function 'iadd'Operator Overload in function 'iadd'"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types, numba

I'm attempting to call a function `inter_1D()` which is defined as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft
from numba import jit, njit, prange

@njit(parallel = True)
def reconstruction(values_fft, Ni, c_max, pos):
   value_inter = np.real(values_fft[0])
   
   # fourier term indexes: f
   for f in prange(1, Ni // 2 + 1):
      w = f * 2 * np.pi / c_max
      value_inter += 2 * np.real(values_fft[f]) * np.cos(w * pos)
      value_inter -= 2 * np.imag(values_fft[f]) * np.sin(w * pos)
   
   value_inter /= Ni
   return value_inter 

def inter_1D(coords, values, pos):
   return reconstruction(fft(values[:-1]), len(values) - 1, coords[-1], pos)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function iadd>) found for signature:
 
 >>> iadd(float64, array(float64, 1d, C))
 
There are 18 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 16 did not match due to:
  Overload of function 'iadd': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
    With argument(s): '(float64, array(float64, 1d, C))':
   No match.
  - Of which 2 did not match due to:
  Operator Overload in function 'iadd': File: unknown: Line unknown.
    With argument(s): '(float64, array(float64, 1d, C))':
   No match for registered cases:
    * (int64, int64) -> int64
    * (int64, uint64) -> int64
    * (uint64, int64) -> int64
    * (uint64, uint64) -> uint64
    * (float32, float32) -> float32
    * (float64, float64) -> float64
    * (complex64, complex64) -> complex64
    * (complex128, complex128) -> complex128

During: typing of intrinsic-call at [FILEPATH]/[FILENAME].py (20)

File "[FILENAME].py", line 20:
def reconstruction(values_fft, Ni, c_max, pos):
    <source elided>
      w = f * 2 * np.pi / c_max
      value_inter += 2 * np.real(values_fft[f]) * np.cos(w * pos)
```

I can change

```py
value_inter += 2 * np.real(values_fft[f]) * np.cos(w * pos)
value_inter -= 2 * np.imag(values_fft[f]) * np.sin(w * pos)
```

to

```
value_inter = value_inter + 2 * np.real(values_fft[f]) * np.cos(w * pos)
value_inter = value_inter - 2 * np.imag(values_fft[f]) * np.sin(w * pos)
```

which changes my error to the following:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Cannot unify float64 and array(float64, 1d, C) for 'value_inter.4', defined at [FILEPATH]/[FILENAME].py (18)

File "[FILENAME].py", line 18:
def reconstruction(values_fft, Ni, c_max, pos):
    <source elided>
   value_inter = np.real(values_fft[0])
   for f in prange(1, Ni // 2 + 1):
   ^

During: typing of assignment at [FILEPATH]/[FILENAME].py (18)

File "[FILENAME].py", line 18:
def reconstruction(values_fft, Ni, c_max, pos):
    <source elided>
   value_inter = np.real(values_fft[0])
   for f in prange(1, Ni // 2 + 1):
   ^
```

Overall, I'm extremely confused about what these errors actually mean, what I should change, and I would be greatly appreciative of any insight anyone might have.

@coder00, a standard usage would be as follows:

```py
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)

pos = 1.2
a = inter_1D(x, y, pos)
# `a` should converge to sin(1.2) as the number of elements in the `x`, `y` arrays increases.
```

It should be noted that the following functions as it should. The whole point of using `@njit` is to speed it up, since this will be called on a repeated basis.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft
from numba import jit, njit, prange

def reconstruction(values_fft, Ni, c_max, pos):
   value_inter = np.real(values_fft[0])

   # fourier term indexes: f
   for f in range(1, Ni // 2 + 1):
      w = f * 2 * np.pi / c_max
      value_inter += 2 * np.real(values_fft[f]) * np.cos(w * pos)
      value_inter -= 2 * np.imag(values_fft[f]) * np.sin(w * pos)

   value_inter /= Ni
   return value_inter 

def inter_1D(coords, values, pos):
   return reconstruction(fft(values[:-1]), len(values) - 1, coords[-1], pos)
```

Comment: Could you please explain more about the input, and provide an example

Comment: @coder00, I edited the above post. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Your code cannot be parallized. The value of value_inter is based on the iteration, as you are going through for loop, and each time you add to the previous  value. you can refer to this link for more info
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/5923

Comment: ndarrays also have a priority attribute that controls interactions with scalar, array scalars and array subclaases.